# Maven Pom Error - Can not find parent for Jersey

Tags: java, maven, jersey

Have Eclipse Juno, maven 2.2.1, and m2eclipse running on a Red Hat Linux platform...

Downloaded a simple example to build a Restful Hello World web service (which works on my OS X computer) but for some odd reason, its not working on my Linux box.

Here's the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
     <artifactId>RESTfulExample</artifactId>
     <packaging>war</packaging>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <name>RESTfulExample Maven Webapp</name>
     <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

     <repositories>
        <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
     </repositories>

     <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.8.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>RESTfulExample</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

When I try to issue an mvn compile from the command line:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building RESTfulExample Maven Webapp
[INFO]    task-segment: [compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).

Project ID: null:jersey-server:bundle:null

 Reason: Cannot find parent: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project for project: null:jersey -server:bundle:null for project null:jersey-server:bundle:null


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 15 17:07:16 PST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Has anyone encountered this issue? I don't understand how it works on my OS X computer but not on Linux (which I don't think is the issue).

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would completely remove the entire `repositories` element in your pom.xml file.  This way maven will use the standard central repository. Then change the version of jersey-server to 1.15 (the latest).

The latest jersey in that java.net repository is dated august 2011, while the standard central maven repository has version 1.15 dated October 30 2012.

I suspect that the reason it works on one machine and not the other is that in your ~/.m2/repository cache you have good cached files on one machine but not on the other.  It may be necessary to delete the entire ~/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey hierarchy and rebuild.  You may have corrupted files there.

Comment: Yes, removing the repositories section and setting the version to 1.15 is what got it working! Thanks you so much!